# SSD to work with PCIe

Tags: ssd, pcie, sata

I recently got a new (to me) computer. It was [a workhorse computer](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01709707) from a few years ago. I'm trying to rig it up to work with an SSD in its new life with me.

Currently the motherboard has SATA II and PCIe x4 slots available. I purchased a [SAMSUNG 850 EVO M.2 SATA III](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA12K3UA7510) drive  which I was hoping would wrok but because of my confusion on how the M.2 spec works the drive I purchased is not directly compatible with my motherboard. I was assuming I could plug it into a PCIe slot (obviously that was wrong), then I was hoping I could get a PCIe to M.2 adapter but because this particular drive is M.2/SATA which means if I get an adapter I'd have to plug it in to a SATA II port which is what I was hoping to avoid is the first place.

Is there something I can buy that can make use of the drive I purchased while not compromising speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking specification of your motherboard (from this [link](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04111619)) I checked that you have one PCI-E connector which will support PCI-E Solid State Drive.
[image]

You have two possible solutions:

**Buy M2 to PCIe adapter:**

- [Addonics M.2 PCIe SSD Adapter X110](http://www.legitreviews.com/addonics-m-2-pcie-ssd-adapter-x110-review_165632) / [$30 in their shop](http://www.shopaddonics.com/Itemdesc.asp?ic=AD2M2S-PX4&eq=&Tp=)

**Buy new SSD drive:**

- [Kingston HyperX Predator 240GB (with HHHL Adapter)](http://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/ssd/shpm2280p2) -> [$180 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104544)
- [Plextor Lite on M6e 256GB](http://www.goplextor.com/Product/Detail/M6e%28A%29_Black_Edition#/Spec) -> [$190 on Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TRVRB0A)

I would reccommend to buy Addonics adapter it is cheaper and has good reviews.

---

**EDIT:**

If you will mount only one SSD you won't need additional power and sata cable (screen below):
[image]
Digging deeper I found two other Addonics adapters which have slot for only one SSD drive and no additional connectors (but only one can fit your SSD, because second one can only fit up to 80 mm M2 cards):

- [ADM2NVMPX4](http://www.addonics.com/products/adm2nvmpx4.php) $19 on their website

Comment: for adapters like this where I "need to run standard SATA data cables to the SATA III ports on the motherboard" is PCIe even being used at all? Is it basically a power source/mounting bracket at that point? This seems like it will make the drive I purchased usable (which is good) but will still be limited to the speed of SATA II ultimately, right? Any insight on why the PCIe versions of these SSDs are more expensive that their SAT brethren?

Comment: (I'm ordering this and will report back after it's installed)

Comment: Just ordered off [Amazon](http://smile.amazon.com/Addonics-PCIE-Adapter-X110-AD2M2S-PX2/dp/B015MVS4O0/) ( I had to wait for a new month's budget cycle to order) It was cheaper on the Addonics site but the shipping was 11 $ so I backed out of that order and went to Amazon.

Comment: Also, the second item in your edit (ADM2NVMPX4) is for M.2 PCIe but my SSD is M.2 SATA and won't work with that adapter. SO yes, a better price but I think ultimately I need that SATA cable going to the actual SATA controller. You can sort of see that in your diagram one column to the right of the highlighted one.

Comment: I got the [AD2M2S-PX2](http://smile.amazon.com/Addonics-PCIE-Adapter-X110-AD2M2S-PX2/dp/B015MVS4O0) in the mail yesterday. I mounted my [M.2 SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA12K3UA7510) in the appropriate SATA slot, plugged in the adapter into a PCIe slot and plugged a SATA cable between it an my motherboard. Then used [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) to [clone my old drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/199068/how-to-upgrade-your-existing-hard-drive-in-under-an-hour/). Shut down, unplugged the old drive, restarted and bam! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Now I just need to expand my primary partition (which apparently is trickier than it sounds because it is not contiguous with the unallocated space on the new drive, whatever that means for an SSD)